# How to log the name of backend that responded a request

Tags: varnish, varnishncsa

I'm using **varnishncsa** to log requests that are taking to long to be answered on my backend servers using the following command:

```
varnishncsa -F '%t "%r" %s %T' | awk '$7 > 10 {print}'
```

I was trying to add information on the backend name but this is not being displayed on **varnishncsa** output:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    std.log("backend_name:" + beresp.backend.name);
}
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work for you because `varnishncsa` uses "client" mode by default.
Enable it using `-b` switch.

Subsequently, this will work:

```
varnishncsa -b -F '%t "%r" %s %T %{VCL_Log:backend_name}x' | awk '$7 > 10 {print}'
```

You might want to check [full explanation](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish/varnish-4-5-log-slow-backend-requests) which includes additional optimization to query slow backend requests.

Comment: thanks! I'm using Varnish 4.1.1 and the varnishncsa command doesn't have the -b option: `varnishncsa: invalid option -- 'b'`; nice blog post, BTW.

Comment: Ah, bummer :) Works fine with Varnish 4.1.5 lol.

Comment: You might then want to put your ```std.log``` statement in ```vcl_recv``` instead and log the value of ```req.backend_hint``` - this will work.